# How do you resolve an SSL configuration with the warning: "Two certificates were found with the same common name."?

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

After installing a new SSL certificate under Apache, I used the 
[RapidSSL Certificate Installation Checker](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO9556) to validate my secured domain.  After typing in my domain, I received a warning and this message:

```
Two certificates were found with the same common name. The certificate installation checker cannot 
determine which is the correct certificate for the Web server. Remove the incorrect certificate 
and then test again.
```

My Apache / SSL configuration is such that I list my new SSL certificate in the same file along with the relevant certifying authorities.  In the SSL configuration, I specify these options:

```
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert-with-ca-chain.txt
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/cert-with-ca-chain.txt
```

Based on comments in the Apache SSL module, such a configuration should be possible:

```
#   Server Certificate Chain:
#   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
#   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
#   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
#   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
#   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
#   certificate for convinience.
```

I looked online for a resolution to this issue, but could find none.
After a while, I did resolve the issue myself.  I want to see what
other people have to say, and then will post my solution so people
doing Apache / SSL setups in the future will have this resource at
their disposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the solution is obviously not to use that configuration but to use a file with a  single certificate for the SSLCertificateFile and the CA's own bundle file for the SSLCertificateChainFile. Exactly how the CA gave it to you in fact. There's no advantage in doing the extra processing, especially when it comes time to renew and you can't remember what you did.

Comment: So, I did something like this to resolve the warning.  I left SSLCertificateFile as-is (ie, containing my SSL certificate along with the CA certs), but I changed SSLCertificateChainFile so as not to include my SSL certificate.  This avoided the duplicate cert warning.  But as you note, it probably entails more processing than necessary if I instead simply nixed the CA certs from SSLCertificateFile.

Comment: BTW, this posting is intended for those vetting Apache / SSL configurations through the RapidSSL checker who receive the warning: "Two certificates were found with the same common name."  I found no other resource online when I searched for that warning message.

Comment: Thanks for this. Fixed it right up. Strangely, Thwate SSL checker showed the error, but sslshopper didn't find the same "Multiple Certs" issue. But the advice about removing the ssl cert from the chain was exactly what needed to happen.